# Show hidden tick labels for series with null values

Tags: javascript, jqplot

I'd like to draw a bar chart that potentially has null values, like this (as `data`):

```
[[['a',null],['b',null],['c',null],['d',null]]]
```

In this case, no tick label is drawn:

[image: no tick labels]

But if I specify tick labels manually, they are shown:

```
ticks: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

[image: manual tick labels]

How can I let jqplot draw the default labels also for null values?

Answer (score 1):

`breakOnNull: true` did the job. My configuration (relevant part):

```
...
seriesDefaults: {
    renderer: jQuery.jqplot.BarRenderer,
    breakOnNull: true
}
....
```